# Local homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the space of real $2\times2$ matrices of rank one and norm one

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the space of all real $2\times 2$ matrices,
>   equipped with the norm $||A||=\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(A^TA)}$, for
>   $A\in\mathcal{M}$ (here $A^T$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $A$
>   and for any $2\times 2$ real matrix $B$, $\mbox{tr}(B)$ denotes its
>   trace). Consider the map $F$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathcal{M}$
>   given by the formula, for any $(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$: $$F(s,t) =
>  \frac{1}{2}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}\cos(t)+\cos(s)&&\sin(t)+\sin(s)\\-\sin(t)+\sin(s)&&\cos(t)-\cos(s)\end{vmatrix}.$$
>   Denote by $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{M}$ the space of all real
>   $2\times2$ matrices of rank one and norm one.
>
> Prove that the image of the map $F$ is the space $\mathcal{N}$ and
>   that the map $F$ is a local homeomorphism to its image (the latter
>   with the induced topology).

My attempt is as follows.

1. Show that $\mbox{Im}(F)=\mathcal{N}$ means to show that $\mbox{Im}(F)\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mbox{Im}(F)$.

For arbitrary tuple $(s,t)$ consider
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\begin{vmatrix}\cos(t)+\cos(s)&&\sin(t)+\sin(s)\\-\sin(t)+\sin(s)&&\cos(t)-\cos(s)\end{vmatrix}, ~A\in\mbox{Im}(F).$$
Note that $\det(A)=0$, therefore rows are linearly dependent and $\dim\mbox{Ker}(A)=1$ ($\dim\mbox{Ker}(A)\neq2$ since $A$ isn't identically zero), so $\mbox{rk}(A)=1$ follows from the rank-nullity theorem.

One can also check directly that $||A||=\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(A^TA)}=1$, so we have proved that $\mbox{Im}(F)\subseteq\mathcal{N}$. How can we show another inclusion -- that *any* $2\times2$ real matrix with rank one and norm one is apparently of that form?

2. Show that $F$ is a local homeomorphism to $\mbox{Im}(F)$.

By definition, homeomorphism is a continuous bijection such that the inverse is also continuous. Here the real issues in my understanding begin. We can show that $F$ is onto by proving that $\mathcal{N}\subseteq\mbox{Im}(F)$ which is essentially my question above. However, how can $F$ be one-to-one and has an inverse if $\det(F)=0$? This immediately implies that matrix isn't invertible and has a non-empty kernel.

I will very appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you mean, $\mathrm{det}(F)=0$? $F$ is not a matrix, nor is it a linear transformation. $F(s,t)$ is a matrix for all $s, t$ but that is not the same as $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I'm not terribly familiar with topology so I don't know whether I've been rigorous enough with this answer. I think it brings the idea across if nothing else.

The set $\mathcal{N}$ can be characterised as the set:
$$
\mathcal{N}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}:a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1\quad\land\quad ad-bc=0\right\}
$$
If we rewrite these conditions a bit, we see that they are:
$$
(a+d)^2+(a-d)^2+(b+c)^2+(b-c)^2=2\\
(a+d)^2-(a-d)^2-(b+c)^2+(b-c)^2=0
$$
Introducing
$$
x=a+d\quad y=a-d\quad z=b+c\quad w=b-c
$$
we get:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=2\\
x^2-y^2-z^2+w^2=0
$$
But this system is equivalent to
$$
x^2+w^2=1\\
y^2+z^2=1
$$
These solutions can be parametrised as:
$$
x=\cos t\quad w=\sin t\\
y=\cos s\quad z=\sin s
$$
The map $(s,t)\rightarrow (x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t),w(s,t))$ is locally a homeomorphism as it essentially just represents a parametrisation of two independent circles with radius $1$ by the angles $s,t$. From here, we recover $a,b,c,d$ as:
$$
a=\frac{\cos t+\cos s}{2}\quad b=\frac{\sin t+\sin s}{2}\quad c=\frac{-\sin t+\sin s}{2}\quad d=\frac{\cos t-\cos s}{2}\quad 
$$
But the map $(x,y,z,w)\rightarrow (a,b,c,d)$ is just a linear transformation and as such also a homeomorphism. The composition $(s,t)\rightarrow(x,y,z,w)\rightarrow(a,b,c,d)\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is precisely the map $F$, so $F$ is indeed a local homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Yes, the map $\Bbb R\to S^1$ is a local homeomorphism, hence so is $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R \to S^1\times S^1$ which is (a scalar multiple of) $(s, t) \mapsto (x, y, z, w)$.

Comment: Good to know I haven't jumped to any conclusion too quickly.

Comment: @Berci Does this map actually represent a homeomorphism from the $2D$ torus to $\mathcal{N}$? I'm trying to imagine it geometrically and this picture seems about right.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. Maybe I will seem naive, but can you explain how you came up with this approach? What was the motivation behind it? Everything is clear when it's explained, but I don't know how could I come up with something like this from nowhere.

Comment: It's kind of hard to say. I first tried writing a system of equations $2a=\cos t+\cos s$ etc. along with the norm and rank conditions but that led nowhere. However, the fact that, say, $2D$ rotations are homeomorphic to a circle and the $\sin, \cos$ that appear here made me think something similar was going on. Also, the condition $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ is just the definition of the $4$-sphere. So I was looking for another algebraic condition and the only one really left was the determinant, $ad-bc=0$.

Comment: Since these are quadratic forms, I decided it couldn't hurt to diagonalise $ad-bc$. After doing that, the $x,y,z,w$ transformation seemed reasonable enough and when I did it the solution popped out. Honestly, I think I was also somewhat lucky for hitting upon a successful approach rather quickly.